# Login authentication using liferay sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-7

I have designed login page for my project.I need to do login integration using liferay sdk.I am not at all understanding how to use liferay sdk in android.Please let me know how to use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn is to follow this [README](https://github.com/liferay-mobile/liferay-android-sdk).

It's quite easy, basically add a dependency to the liferay android SDK, create a config object and make the call to the remote service you want (listed under IP/api/jsonws)

```
GroupService service = ServiceBuilder.build(GroupService.class);
Call<JSONArray> call = service.getUserSitesGroups();

Config config = new Config.Builder("http://_YOUR_IP_:8080")
  .auth(new BasicAuthentication("test@liferay.com", "test"))
  .build();

JSONArray groups = call.execute(config);
```

Comment: Thanks nhpatt!! I tried this one.I have gone through README. But I am not understanding where and how to use code.Please help me out.

Comment: Inside any activity. If you need more detailed help, please post in the forums: https://community.liferay.com/es/forums

Comment: Hi nhpatt. The given community link is not opening.

Comment: Hey nhpatt.I downloaded the liferay SDK with screenlet from GitHub.I am not understanding how to use it.Since it is meged with IOS.Can you please help me out.

Comment: What's the problem? Can you specify it? Are you following the documentation? https://dev.liferay.com/es/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-1/preparing-android-projects-for-liferay-screens

Comment: Yes.But I have not installed liferay in my system.I have just added the dependencies in build gradle file.

Comment: I didnt install liferay portal in my system.I am just using dependencies in build gradle file.